# Solving the complex integral $ \int_{C} \frac{e^{z}-1}{z^{4}}dz $

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

This is the example from the Churchill's textbook
$ \int_{C} \frac{e^{z}-1}{z^{4}}dz $, where C is the positively oriented unit circle |z| = 1. 
To determine the residue of the function,
they used the Maclaurin series representation
$e^{z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n!}$ 
and used it to write
$\frac{e^{z}-1}{z^{5}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n-5}}{n!}$.

I just don't understand why they use $ z^5 $ rather than $z ^4$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you should look at $\frac {e^{z}-1} {z^{5}}$. Exapand $e^{z}$ to see that the coefficient of $\frac 1 z$ is $\frac 1 {3!}$. This is the residue at $0$.

Comment: use the Cauchy Integral Formula $$\int_C\dfrac{f(z)dz}{z^n}=2\pi i\dfrac{f^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

1.You can use the Residue Theorem to get the answer .

$$\int_{C}\frac{e^{z}-1}{z^{4}}\,dz=2i\pi\text{Res}_{z=0}\frac{e^{z}-1}{z^{4}}=\frac{2i\pi}{6}=\frac{i\pi}{3}$$.

2. You can use the Cauchy Integral formula. You have
   $$\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw=f(w)$$.
   Differentiate this to get:-
   $$f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2i\pi}\int_{C}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^{n+1}}\,dw$$. Where $f$ is a holomorphic function.
   Take $f(z)=e^{z}-1$ and evaluate at $z=0$ to get the answer as $\frac{2i\pi f^{3}(0)}{3!}=\frac{i\pi}{3}$.
3. Directly Use Taylor's Theorem and the Interchange of integral and summation within the radius of convergence of the power series expansion . Then you can integrate the maclaurin expansion. You will get that only the integral $\int_{C}\frac{1}{3!}\frac{z^{3}}{z^{4}}\,dz$ is non-zero. All others are zero. You can actually prove that $\int_{C}\frac{1}{z^{n}}\,dz=0$ for $n\neq -1$.  It is really easy. Just use the parametrization of $z=e^{it},\,0\leq t\leq 2\pi$.